# PMM and VCPKG cannot find package directory

Tags: c++, cmake, vcpkg, pmm

I'm trying out the [pmm](https://github.com/vector-of-bool/pmm) tool to add libraries to my project. I've opt'ed for the VCPKG variant. The `pmm` installs fine, packages are installed, but then the cmake command
`find_package(x)`, says it cannot find the package.
After hours of fiddling around, I found where the packages are getting installed and manually added the path to cmake. This works, but of course it's very dissatisfying because I am not sure how universal this path would be. How can I make this work without providing that path? Or is this path always needed and I have not fully understood the documentation? Any insight would be much appreciated. Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(pmmAndVcpkg VERSION 0.0.0)

set(VCPKG_REV 2022.05.10)

include(pmm.cmake)
pmm(
    VCPKG
    REVISION ${VCPKG_REV}
    REQUIRES fmt
)

# WHY DO I NEED THIS SECTION????
################################

set(VCPKG_PATH $ENV{HOME}/.local/share/pmm/${PMM_VERSION_INIT}/vcpkg-${VCPKG_REV}/packages)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} ${VCPKG_PATH} ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} ${VCPKG_PATH} ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
################################

find_package(fmt CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE fmt)
```

Apart from this file I only added the `pmm.cmake` file as required, and a `main.cpp` file to assert I can link to the library.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add the triplet:

```
pmm(
    VCPKG
    REVISION ${VCPKG_REV}
    TRIPLET ${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}-${PLATFORM}
    REQUIRES fmt
)
```